# Significato di "farsi le sue ragioni" in questo brano

Tags: meaning

Nel racconto *Fosforo* dal libro *Il sistema periodico*, di Primo Levi, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Principalmente, non riuscivo a capire come non bastasse la volontà di quel lui a tagliare il nodo: era inconcepibile, scandaloso. C’era quest’uomo, che Giulia mi aveva altre volte descritto come generoso, solido, innamorato e serio; possedeva quella ragazza, scarmigliata e splendida nella sua rabbia, che mi si stava dibattendo fra gli avambracci impegnati nella guida; e invece di piombare a Milano e **farsi le sue ragioni**, se ne stava annidato in non so piú quale caserma di frontiera a difendere la patria.

Il "quel lui" e il "quest’uomo" menzionati nel testo sono il fidanzato di Giulia. L'io narrante è Primo Levi che accompagnanava Giulia a casa dei genitori di questo fidanzato.

Ecco un brano precedente in cui si può capire la ragione per cui Giulia voleva incontrarsi con questi genitori (il soggetto della prima frase è Giulia):

> [...] era furiosa perché i genitori di lui avevano detto di no, e volava al contrattacco. Perché lo avevano detto? – Per loro non sono abbastanza bella, capisci? – ringhiò, [...].

Non capisco il significato della locuzione "farsi le sue ragioni" che appare nel testo. Alla [voce "ragione" del vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ragione) ho trovato

> *Farsi una r. di qualche cosa*, dolorosa o spiacevole, rassegnarsi ad accettarla come un fatto, dominando il dolore o il disappunto con la riflessione, riconoscendone l’inevitabilità: *ha pianto per molto tempo il marito morto, ma ormai se ne è fatta una r.*

Tuttavia, non credo che questo significato abbia molto senso nel contesto del testo: Levi si starebbe rammaricando del fatto che il fidanzato di Giulia non venisse a Milano per rassegnarsi della situazione? Non mi sembra logico. Per questa ragione vi chiedo: sapresti spiegarmi cosa vuol dire "farsi le sue ragioni" nel primo brano citato?

Comment: Un altro significato è "far valere le sue/proprie ragioni", cioé esporle, difenderle, avvalersene.

Answer (score 2):

Il brano descrive una situazione in cui i genitori del fidanzato di Giulia non vogliono dare ai due fidanzati la benedizione per il matrimonio. Primo Levi si stupisce quindi che il fidanzato, impegnato nel servizio militare, non torni immediatamente a Milano a far valere le proprie ragioni (**"farsi le sue ragioni"**), cioè a obbligare i genitori a riconsiderare quel "no", operazione nella quale riesce brillantemente Giulia.

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE e grazie della risposta. Allora, se ho capito bene, il significato di "farsi le sue reagioni" sarebbe lo stesso di "far valere le proprie ragioni", che, secondo il Treccani significa "obbligare altri a riconoscere i nostri diritti, con la persuasione, con la forza, o ricorrendo alla giustizia", no?

Comment: Esatto, il significato dovrebbe essere proprio questo!