# Significato di "li ho fatti diventare alti cosí" in questo contesto

Tags: meaning

Nel racconto *Fosforo* dal libro *Il sistema periodico*, di Primo Levi, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Giulia uscí dopo due ore, anzi, eruppe dal portone come un proiettile da un obice. Non occorreva farle domande per sapere come era andata: – **Li ho fatti diventare alti cosí**, – mi disse, tutta rossa in viso e ancora ansimante. Feci il mio miglior sforzo per congratularmi con lei in modo credibile, ma [...]. Ora che era sollevata dal suo peso, e allegra di vittoria, mi guardò diritto negli occhi, [...].
>       Giulia si sposò pochi mesi dopo, [...].

La frase in grassetto fa riferimento ai genitori del fidanzato di Giulia, che lei era andata a incontrare per le ragioni spiegate in questa [altra domanda](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/13115): avevano rifiutato il matrimonio dei due fidanzati perché consideravono che lei non era abbastanza bella.

Non capisco il significato della frase "li ho fatti diventare alti cosí". Ho cercato alla [voce "alto" del vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/alto1), ma non ho saputo trovare nessuna accezione figurata di questo aggettivo che abbia senso nel contesto del passaggio.

Potreste spiegarmi che cosa vuol dire questa frase?

Comment: Dipende: quando uno è contento, sembra che cresca di statura; se è umiliato, sembra che diventi piccolo. Se Giulia ha raggiunto il suo obiettivo lusingando i possibili suoceri, li ha visti più alti; se li ha umiliati, li ha visti piccoli.

Comment: @egreg - in effetti non si capisce quale sia esattamente l’esito della visita ai possibili suoceri, però far diventare qualcuno “alto” nel senso di lusingare, inorgoglire, non l’ho mai sentito dire. Il contrario sì.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Da quanto si può desumere dal testo riportato nella domanda, la frase:

> li ho fatti diventare alti così

potrebbe significare, in realtà, che li ha fatti diventare “piccoli così” se l’espressione è accompagnata da un gesto con la mano come quello illustrato sotto:

[image]

Giulia, quindi, starebbe dicendo che è riuscita a mettere i possibili futuri suoceri al loro posto, dopo che inizialmente l’avevano rifiutata come fidanzata del figlio.